# How to get comment meta values by post ID

Tags: theme-development, comments

I can get comment meta value by a comment ID. But if I want to retrieve a comment meta value of a single post's comments, how should I go?

Comment: A single post can have multiple comments, each of which will have their own meta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`get_comments`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) allows you to select comments based on meta value. So, supposing you are on a single post page, so the current post is known, you would do this:

```
$comments = get_comments (array ('meta_key'=> 'your_meta_key'));
```

This will give you all comments with that specific meta key. You can even select them for a specific meta value, like this:

```
$comments = get_comments (array ('meta_key'=> 'your_meta_key', 'meta_value'=> 'your_meta_value'));
```

For instance, if you have a meta key called 'rating' and you want all comments that give the rating '5', you would do:

```
$comments = get_comments (array ('meta_key'=> 'rating', 'meta_value'=> '5'));
```

Beware that `$comments` returns as an array of comment objects, so printing goes like this:

```
foreach($comments as $comment) {
  echo ($comment->comment_content);
  echo get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true)
  }
```

Comment: I sincerely thought there is a way to get the array of comments with their meta without creating custom JOIN SQL or using the loop, as you describe above.

Comment: @AdrianP. did you find an alternative solution for this?

Comment: @coding-dude.com I ended up doing it the WP way as the reply above.